# Clear cookies when using ASWebAuthenticationSession

Tags: swift, cookies, aswebauthenticationsession

How to clear cookies when using ASWebAuthenticationSession, the scenario is  like, a different user can use the same device to login. If a user has already used it with SSO done, app is not insisting SSO for the new user.

So need to clear cookies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Before calling session `session.start()` you need to set one specific property:
`session.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true`.

It's will start clear session and will not set new cookies.

Comment: prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true is available only for iOS 13 only.